# How to return an Eigen expression that references local variables?

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to make a function that returns an Eigen expression. Some inputs to this expression are local variables in that function. However as the function returns these local variables go out of scope. Later when the expression is evaluated some garbage data is read producing wrong result.

Simple example:

```
template<typename T>
auto f(const T& x){
    Eigen::ArrayXXd temp = exp(x);
    return temp * (1 - temp);
}
```

[live example](https://godbolt.org/z/ETTxbZ)

EDIT2: Another, more realistic example that is not just element wise operation:

```
template <typename T>
auto softmax(const T& x){
    Eigen::ArrayXXd tmp = exp(x - x.maxCoeff());
    return tmp / tmp.sum();
}
```

Is there a way to extend the lifetime of such a local variable to the lifetime of the expression? Or is there no other way than to evaluate the result before returning it from the function?

EDIT: I am looking for ways to optimize an existing library. So I can not change function signature too much - the return type must be Eigen expression.

Comment: Certainly not the answer you are looking for, but as a quick hack, you can create a struct that stores the expression and all related variables and return that instead. Another thing that might help are constant references to extend a variables lifetime: https://blog.galowicz.de/2016/03/23/const_reference_to_temporary_object/

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Are you (only) evaluating element-wise functions (as in your example)? In that case you should ideally implement a custom functor object. However, clang and gcc seem to be pretty aware of common sub-expressions and optimize them away, if you just calculate `x.exp()*(1.0-x.exp())`: https://godbolt.org/z/j8B8AK (notice that both finish with a `vsubpd` and `vmulpd` depending on the same `exp(x)` intermediate). So this might be premature optimization (and evaluating into a temporary can actually make things worse).

Comment: The library in question is [Stan Math](https://github.com/stan-dev/math). Right now all functions return only Eigen::Matrix objects. I would like to generalize this to general expressions. While many functions do work element-wise, not all of them do. Also I avoid functors, as I don't know how reliably they can be vectorized. I know most operations in Eigen go down to assembly level to ensure vectorization. While compiler removing duplicated `exp` looks promising, I am not sure how reliable that is with more complex expressions.

Comment: To get reliable vectorization with functors, you'd need to provide your own functor structs, (have a look at how Eigen implements its functors). If you don't want to go down that rabbit hole, just make your functions return by value -- at the moment, your `temp` object requires allocation anyway, in many cases your return-object gets optimized away by RVO, and you don't have to worry about surprises when using your functions.

Comment: You might be missunderstanding what I am trying to optimize. It is not about RVO. I want to return EIgen expressions, so that calling multiple functions like `a(b(c(x)))` can construct and evaluate single expression, avoiding intermediate temporary matrices where possible (some temporaries in function bodies are unavoidable, like `temp` in the example in question).

Can you give me an example of which functors in Eigen should I look into?

Comment: You can look here for Eigen's functors: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/Core/functors/UnaryFunctors.h Also, the `temp` in your example is avoidable (as it is still an element-wise function), maybe show an example where you think the temporary really is not avoidable.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I added another example.

Comment: This would be possible using custom expressions, but that is non-trivial. Even Eigen itself has some functions return by value, e.g., [`normalized()`](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/Core/Dot.h#L123) (which has a similar dependency). Btw, if you add `@chtz` to your answers, I would get notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by allocating these "local variables" on heap instead. They need to be owned by the returned expression, so the memory is released once the returned expression goes out of scope. To do that we need a custom Eigen expression:

```
template <class ArgType, typename... Ptrs>
class Holder;

namespace Eigen {
namespace internal {
template <class ArgType, typename... Ptrs>
struct traits<Holder<ArgType, Ptrs...>> {
  typedef typename ArgType::StorageKind StorageKind;
  typedef typename traits<ArgType>::XprKind XprKind;
  typedef typename ArgType::StorageIndex StorageIndex;
  typedef typename ArgType::Scalar Scalar;
  enum {
    Flags = ArgType::Flags & RowMajorBit,
    RowsAtCompileTime = ArgType::RowsAtCompileTime,
    ColsAtCompileTime = ArgType::ColsAtCompileTime,
    MaxRowsAtCompileTime = ArgType::MaxRowsAtCompileTime,
    MaxColsAtCompileTime = ArgType::MaxColsAtCompileTime
  };
};
}  // namespace internal
}  // namespace Eigen

template <typename ArgType, typename... Ptrs>
class Holder
    : public Eigen::internal::dense_xpr_base<Holder<ArgType, Ptrs...>>::type {
 public:
  Holder(const ArgType& arg, Ptrs*... pointers)
      : m_arg(arg), m_unique_ptrs(std::unique_ptr<Ptrs>(pointers)...) {}
  typedef typename Eigen::internal::ref_selector<Holder<ArgType, Ptrs...>>::type
      Nested;
  typedef Eigen::Index Index;
  Index rows() const { return m_arg.rows(); }
  Index cols() const { return m_arg.cols(); }
  typedef typename Eigen::internal::ref_selector<ArgType>::type ArgTypeNested;
  ArgTypeNested m_arg;
  std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Ptrs>...> m_unique_ptrs;
};

namespace Eigen {
namespace internal {
template <typename ArgType, typename... Ptrs>
struct evaluator<Holder<ArgType, Ptrs...>> : evaluator_base<Holder<ArgType>> {
  typedef Holder<ArgType, Ptrs...> XprType;
  typedef typename nested_eval<ArgType, 1>::type ArgTypeNested;
  typedef typename remove_all<ArgTypeNested>::type ArgTypeNestedCleaned;
  typedef typename XprType::CoeffReturnType CoeffReturnType;
  enum {
    CoeffReadCost = evaluator<ArgTypeNestedCleaned>::CoeffReadCost,
    Flags = evaluator<ArgTypeNestedCleaned>::Flags
            & (HereditaryBits | LinearAccessBit | PacketAccessBit),
    Alignment = Unaligned & evaluator<ArgTypeNestedCleaned>::Alignment,
  };

  evaluator<ArgTypeNestedCleaned> m_argImpl;

  evaluator(const XprType& xpr) : m_argImpl(xpr.m_arg) {}

  EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE CoeffReturnType coeff(Index row, Index col) const {
    CoeffReturnType val = m_argImpl.coeff(row, col);
    return val;
  }

  EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE CoeffReturnType coeff(Index index) const {
    CoeffReturnType val = m_argImpl.coeff(index);
    return val;
  }

  template <int LoadMode, typename PacketType>
  EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE PacketType packet(Index row, Index col) const {
    return m_argImpl.template packet<LoadMode, PacketType>(row, col);
  }

  template <int LoadMode, typename PacketType>
  EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE PacketType packet(Index index) const {
    return m_argImpl.template packet<LoadMode, PacketType>(index);
  }
};
}  // namespace internal
}  // namespace Eigen

template <typename T, typename... Ptrs>
Holder<T, Ptrs...> makeHolder(const T& arg, Ptrs*... pointers) {
  return Holder<T, Ptrs...>(arg, pointers...);
}
```

So the function in question can be implemented like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto f(const T& x){
    auto* temp = new Eigen::ArrayXXd(exp(x));
    return makeHolder(*temp * (1 - *temp), temp);
}
```

This is quite complex and has another downside of additional dynamic memory allocations. But it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++14 you can use *init-capture list* to store `temp` as data member of closure generated by lambda expression:

```
template<typename T>
auto f2(const T& x) {
    return [temp = exp(x).eval()](){ return temp * (1-temp); };
}
```

the syntax of call is funny:

```
Eigen::ArrayXXd y = f2(x)();
```

but it works as expected, because temporary object created by `f2(x)` is destroyed at the end of full expression, so result can be correctly evaluted by `y = ..` because `temp` is still alive.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/VyU2RV)

Comment: That is a nice trick, but as soon as you do `auto y = f2(x)();` you did not gain anything (I think) -- actually, putting temporaries into expressions is actually what happened in Eigen 2.x with matrix products (and this became a big mess when people started using `auto`). If you just want to do `ArrayXXd y = f2(x);` you can just make `f2` return by value (should result in the same, due to RVO).